# Find expected value of a uniform discrete RV in the interval $[2^a,2^b]$

Tags: probability

This is Problem 2.18 from Tsitsiklis, Bertsekas, Introduction to Probability, 2nd edition.

[image: problem]

[image: solution]

I follow for $E[X] = \sum_{k=a}^b {1 \over (b-a+1)} 2^k$.

How do you derive ${2^{b+1} - 2^a \over b-a+1}$ from that? The confusion is specifically since the figure for $(1 + 2 + ... + 2^{b-a})$ seems to get ignored.

Comment: Have you learnt geometric series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) tells us that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}r^i = 1+r+r^2 + \ldots +r^{n-1}=\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$

Hence

$$\sum_{i=0}^{b-a}2^i = 1+2+2^2 + \ldots +2^{b-a}=\frac{2^{b-a+1}-1}{2-1}=2^{b-a+1}-1$$